# How to find highlighted text from Word file in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ms-office, office-interop

The question would have been simple but an extra clause added to it has proved to be a big headache for me. The catch here is that I do not need all highlighted "words" but "phrases" from the Word file. I have written the following code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Word.ApplicationClass wordObject = new Word.ApplicationClass();
        wordObject.Visible = false;
        object file = "D:\\mywordfile.docx";
        object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Word.Document thisDoc = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
        List<string> wordHighlights = new List<string>();

        //Let myRange be some Range which has my text under consideration

        int prevStart = 0;
        int prevEnd = 0;
        int thisStart = 0;
        int thisEnd = 0;
        string tempStr = "";
        foreach (Word.Range cellWordRange in myRange.Words)
        {
            if (cellWordRange.HighlightColorIndex.ToString() == "wdNoHighlight")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                thisStart = cellWordRange.Start;
                thisEnd = cellWordRange.End;
                string cellWordText = cellWordRange.Text.Trim();
                if (cellWordText.Length >= 1)   // valid word length, non-whitespace
                {
                    if (thisStart == prevEnd)    // If this word is contiguously highlighted with previous highlighted word
                    {
                        tempStr = String.Concat(tempStr, " "+cellWordText);  // Concatenate with previous contiguously highlighted word
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (tempStr.Length > 0)    // If some string has been concatenated in previous iterations
                        {
                            wordHighlights.Add(tempStr);
                        }
                        tempStr = "";
                        tempStr = cellWordText;
                    }
                }
                prevStart = thisStart;
                prevEnd = thisEnd;
            }
        }

        foreach (string highlightedString in wordHighlights)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(highlightedString);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception j)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(j.Message);
    }
}
```

Now consider the following text:

*Le thé vert a un rôle dans la diminution du cholestérol, la combustion des graisses, la prévention du diabète et les AVC, et conjurer la démence.*

Now suppose someone highlighted "*du cholestérol*", my code obviously selects two words "*du*" and "*cholestérol*". How can I make a continuously highlighted area appear as a single word? I mean "*du cholestérol*" should be returned as one entity in the `List`. Any logic that we scan the document char by char, mark the starting point of highlighting as starting point of selection, and the endpoint of highlighting as end point of selection?

P.S.: If there is a library with required capabilities in any other language, please let me know as the scenario is not language specific. I need only to get the desired results somehow.

**EDIT:** Modified the code with `Start` and `End` as suggested by Oliver Hanappi. But the problem still lies that if there are two such highlighted phrases, separated only by a white space, the program considers both phrases as one. Simply because it reads the `Words` and not spaces. May be some edits required around `if (thisStart == prevEnd)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this far more efficiently with Find which will search more quickly and select all the contiguous text which matches. See the reference here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb258967%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Here is an example in VBA which prints all occurrences of highlighted text :

```
Sub TestFind()

  Dim myRange As Range

  Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content    '    search entire document

  With myRange.Find

    .Highlight = True

    Do While .Execute = True     '   loop while highlighted text is found

      Debug.Print myRange.Text   '   myRange is changed to contain the found text

    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you understand better.

Comment: What I did is:
`objRange.Find.Highlight = 1;`
`objRange.Find.Forward = true;`
`objRange.Find.Execute();`

Here: [Find.Highlight on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.highlight(v=office.14).aspx) I find things confusing, it says Highlight can be set to True, False, but when I try setting true, it says only `int` can be assigned.

And what arguments should I pass to `Execute()`? Obviously I can't set anything in first argument `FindText`. I kept `MatchWholeWord`, `Format` as `true` and it returned `true`. But how to get all the `string` that matched?

Comment: As far as I have searched, I think `Find` just returns a bool value indicating whether the parameters being searched for were found in the `Range` or not. It doesn't actually Find the matching text as it happens in MS-Word. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Edited answer to give example.

Comment: Sorry the problem was basically in C#. I tried to find an analogy between your VBA code and C# members of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, but unfortunately could not get things like `Debug` and `Print` in C#.

Comment: Debug.Print is just to show on the console. You don't have Word to try this out? In Word, just find the Visual Basic editor and you can paste the example. I don't know C#.

Comment: I have Word but I was using this in a C# program, and secondly unfortunately I do not know VB much. I'll still try to do it along in VB. But as far as I can understand this code (I am not sure, though), it may not return the highlighted phrases separately but print all those words that match the `Highlight = True` criteria. (Check my comment on the other answer, it was close but just a minor miss) Well, I will try this as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK so I tried your VBA code in word macro, unfortunately I got only the first contiguous highlighted text. It didn't show me all of them. However, using Advanced Find option on the GUI does walk me through all of them. So I am now trying to figure out how to execute this VBA again and again (like the Next button on Home > Find > Advanced Find > Format > Highlight option in MS Word).

Comment: In fact it's very easy to find the next occurrence (I've just found time to test this). You just Execute() on the Find object returned previously. I'll update my example in a few minutes to show you how.

Comment: You won't believe it, your script worked perfectly and it tempted me to learn basics of VB.NET within an hour. The Find.Execute() and Range.Find.Highlight implementation in C# is terrible. I created a class library in VB.NET using the same code and added a reference to it in my C# project. It was perfect. I will be adding the actual code how I implemented this by the end of the day. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help and will be interested to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.start.aspx) and [End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.end.aspx) properties of the ranges and check whether the end of the first range equals the start of the second.

As an alternative, you may [move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.move.aspx) the range by one word (see WdUnits.wdWord) and then check if the moved start and end equals the start and end of the second word.

Comment: This has been great! I used `Start` and `End` and it worked for highlighted spaces. And yes, `move()` shall work without any problem. BUT still a minor thing remains uncovered: These methods do not consider spaces between words. So just in case: _"This is a wonderful morning."_ Here I highlight _a wonderful_ then leave a space unhighlighted, and then again highlight _morning_. So what to do for two consecutive "phrases" separated by just a space?

Comment: Can I make use of `WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyCharsWSpaces` and `WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyCharacters` in some way to find that space between two consecutive highlighted phrases that are separated just by a whitespace (as in my example above)? If yes can you show my a small code sample how to use them on a `Range`? Sorry I am just out of any idea over this and that was just a vague assumption of mine.

Answer (score 0):

grahamj42 answer is ok, i've translated it to C#.
If you want to find matches in the whole document use:

```
Word.Range content = thisDoc.Content
```

But remember that this is only mainStoryRange, if you want to match words in, for example footnotes you need to use:

```
Word.StoryRanges stories = null;
stories = thisDoc.StoryRanges;
Word.Range footnoteRange = stories[Word.WdStoryType.wdFootnotesStory]
```

My code:

```
Word.Find find = null;
Word.Range duplicate = null;
try
{
    duplicate = range.Duplicate;
    find = duplicate.Find;
    find.Highlight = 1;

    object str = "";
    object missing = System.Type.Missing;
    object objTrue = true;
    object replace = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceNone;

    bool result = find.Execute(ref str, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref objTrue, ref str, ref replace, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    while (result)
    {
        // code to store range text
        // use duplicate.Text property
        result = find.Execute(ref str, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref objTrue, ref str, ref replace, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (find != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(find);
    if (duplicate != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(duplicate);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I started with Oliver's logic, things seemed to be fine, but testing revealed that this method does not take into account white spaces. So highlighted phrases separated by just a space were not getting separated. I used the VB code approach provided by grahamj42 and added it as a class library and included the reference in my C# windows forms project.

My C# Windows form project:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

and then I changed the `try` block as:

```
Word.ApplicationClass wordObject = new Word.ApplicationClass();
wordObject.Visible = false;
object file = "D:\\mywordfile.docx";
object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Document thisDoc = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);

List<string> wordHighlights = new List<string>();


// Let myRange be some Range, which has been already selected programatically here


WordMacroClasses.Highlighting macroObj = new WordMacroClasses.Highlighting();
List<string> hiWords = macroObj.HighlightRange(myRange, myRange.End);
foreach (string hitext in hiWords)
{
    wordHighlights.Add(hitext);
}
```

And here is the `Range.Find` code in VB class library which simply accepts the `Range` and its `Range.Last` and returns a `List(Of String)`:

```
Public Class Highlighting
    Public Function HighlightRange(ByVal myRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range, ByVal rangeLimit As Integer) As List(Of String)

        Dim Highlights As New List(Of String)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0

        With myRange.Find
            .Highlight = True
            Do While .Execute = True     ' loop while highlighted text is found

                If (myRange.Start < rangeLimit) Then Highlights.Add(myRange.Text)

            Loop
        End With
        Return Highlights
    End Function
End Class
```